# Joomla online Store Administration

Tags: mysql, joomla, virtuemart

Does anyone have recommendations on the best Online Store for non-technical users of Joomla?  I have been told that VirtueMart is a good option. Are there better ones?

Comment: VirtueMart is a shopping cart/online store ... Are you looking for an online store or DB admin component?

Comment: Why would you want a DB admin tool made available to non-technical users...seems you're begging for disaster there.  Perhaps specifying what kind of administration you need will clarify.

Comment: I am looking for an online store that non-technical users can add products to. --basically marketing people.

Comment: Have always found VirtueMart far too big, prefer something a little smaller but still powerful like JoomShopping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...that is definately not a db/mysql admin tool.  VM is definately an answer, though there's lovers and haters of it. It's somewhat extensive in it's features, so if that's a concern, I'd check the [Joomla eCommerce Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart) to see others that may be more appropriate.  They're rated to give you some idea of what might be what you're looking for.